# Como seleccionar filas de una tabla donde los minutos del campo fecha sean múltiplos de 5

Tags: sql-server, datetime, select

Buenas, 
necesito coger los registros donde los minutos del campo fecha sean múltiplos de 5 , lo intente así:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_Datos 
WHERE col_Fecha>CONVERT(datetime, '2017-09-06' , 103) 
and col_Fecha like '%:05%' 
or col_Fecha like '%:10%' 
or col_Fecha like '%:15%'
or col_Fecha like '%:20%'
or col_Fecha like '%:25%' 
or col_Fecha like '%:30%' 
or col_Fecha like '%:35%' 
or col_Fecha like '%:40%'
or col_Fecha like '%:45%' 
or col_Fecha like '%:50%' 
or col_Fecha like '%:55%' 
or col_Fecha like '%:00:%'--Este ultimo, al poner el segundo ':' no filtra
```

el ultimo no funciona y no me parece una forma muy correcta de hacerlo, ¿alguna idea?
gracias

Comment: cuál es el tipo de dato de `col_Fecha`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta asi :

```
Where datepart(minute, col_fecha) % 5 = 0
```

Usando el operador de Modulo ( % ) te devolvera el remanente de la division de los minutos entre 5, si es 0 es por que es multiplo de 5.

Saludos,

Comment: funciona a la perfección gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar simplemente:

```
Where col_Fecha like '%:_0%' 
or col_Fecha like '%:_5%'
```

Ya que múltiplo de 5 es cualquiera terminado en 5 o 0.

Comment: Pero esto no sólo hace que sea el minuto un múltiplo de 5, sino que los segundos también

Comment: Que formato tiene `col_fecha`?

Comment: funciona , gracias!